# get orders by custom field (meta data)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, meta-query

I want to loop through my orders and get only the orders with a specific custom field and value.

```
function lwb_5483845() {

    $args = array(
        'limit' => 9999,
        'return' => 'ids',
        'meta_query' => array(

            'key' => 'lwb_pickup_time_email_notification',
            'value' => '31-07-2022',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    );
    
    $query = new WC_Order_Query( $args );
    $orders = $query->get_orders();
    
    foreach( $orders as $order_id ) {
        echo $order_id . '<br />';
    }

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'lwb_5483845', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 2):

`meta_query` is not enabled (by default at least) for WC_Order_Query.  To make this work, you need to use the `meta_key`, `meta_value`, `meta_value_num` and `meta_compare` parameters.

This is detailed in this answer [discussing how meta_query isn't active](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/337876).

So in your case, you could do:

```
function lwb_5483845() {

  $args = array(
    'limit' => 9999,
    'return' => 'ids',
    'meta_key' => 'lwb_pickup_time_email_notification',
    'meta_value' => '31-07-2022',
    'meta_compare' => '='
  );

  $query = new WC_Order_Query( $args );
  $orders = $query->get_orders();

  foreach( $orders as $order_id ) {
    echo $order_id . '<br />';
  }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'lwb_5483845', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: worked on Woocommerce 7.4.1

Answer (score 0):

The `meta_query` index need to be an array of array, because you can set multiple where statements :

```
function lwb_5483845() {

    $args = array(
        'limit' => 9999,
        'return' => 'ids',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'lwb_pickup_time_email_notification',
                'value' => '31-07-2022',
                'compare' => '=',
            ),
        ),
    );
    
    $query = new WC_Order_Query( $args );
    $orders = $query->get_orders();
    
    foreach( $orders as $order_id ) {
        echo $order_id . '<br />';
    }

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'lwb_5483845', 10, 2 );
```